# どこに Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * を設定しますか

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cors

Laravel と Vue で開発をしているのですが、このようなエラーが出てしまい困っています。
どこに `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` を設定すれば解決できますか？

[image: blocked by CORS policy]

Comment: おそらく問題点はACAOではなくlocalhostと127.0.0.1でホスト名が揺れている点かと思います。

Comment: laravel cors をキーワードにググって調べるぐらいのことはしましたか？

Answer (score 1):

私は`.htaccess`ファイルに設定しています。
以下のコードを`.htaccess`に追加します。

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"
   Header add Access-Control-Max-Age 86400
</IfModule>
```

このファイルはpublicフォルダにあります。もし存在しない場合は、以下の画像を参考に
`.htaccess.example`を`.htaccess`にリネームしてみてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]